# PHP Session variables lost in subdirectory level on WAMP

Tags: php, session, wamp, subdirectory, file-structure

PHP sessions work as expected in root directory, and one directory deep. Directories that exist 2 deep end up with a new session id, and all session varaibles are lost.

I include a file `config.inc.php` (absolute path) into all pages which calls `session_start()` and initializes the SESSION variables. I found a PHP directive setting that seems to mention subdirectories, but it looks like it is referring to subdirectories of temporarily stored session files.

I've double checked using the HTTPFox firefox plugin, as soon as I visit any page 2 levels deep, the session is gone, and and a new session ID is issued. Very Strange...

Comment: session variables don't get "lost". You're probably losing the session **COOKIE**. leading to a new+empty session being created.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. See my answer below.

If we're being semantic, it would be valid to say that I lost a variable, if I defined the variable, gave it a value, and then it  inexplicably becomes inaccessible. I "lost" my session variables, due to the current session cookie being overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it looks like I was writing my URLS to those particular directories using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`... The different domain caused the browser to think it was a different website, I guess. Changing this solved my problem.